# Does a convergent subsequence guarantee that the original sequence is also convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to get the intuition on the title statement or find a counterexample.

I know that if a sequence converges, then every subsequence of it converges as well.

But I am not sure that if a subsequence converges, then that guarantees that the original sequence also converges. My intuition says it's not true but I m struggling to find a counterexample.

Comment: How about $$x_n = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\ 0 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\ \end{cases}$$ The even and odd subsequences are convergent, but the sequence itself is not.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very clear counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.  A counterexample can be easily constructed by taking two convergent sequences, say $a_n$ and $b_n$, which converge to different limits, ie. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = a \neq b = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n$, and then creating a new sequence $c_n$ such that

\begin{equation}
c_n = 
\begin{cases}
a_n &\text{ if $n$ is even}\\
b_n &\text{ if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here, the subsequence of even terms converges to $a$, and the subsequence of odd terms converges to $b$. Since $a\neq b$, $c_n$ does not converge. The proof follows from considering the definition of the limit of a sequence (the proof is not particularly difficult, and is a good exercise).

More complex sequences consisting of more than two convergent subsequences can also be created by this method (try it!).

A very simple example is provided by [Bungo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169852/bungo) in their comment, which is the sequence

\begin{equation}
x_n = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if $n$ is even}\\
0 &\text{ if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The subsequences consisting of all $1$s and all $0$s converge to $1$ and $0$ respectively, whereas $x_n$ does not converge.

---

Also of interest to you might be the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20theorem%20states%20that%20each,called%20the%20sequential%20compactness%20theorem.), which establishes that every *bounded* (and not necessarily convergent) sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence. The proof of the statement is easy to follow and will likely give you a better idea of convergence of subsequences.

Comment: Thank you ! This is a great explanation.